# How to Mock TCPClient by implementing the interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to computer science and have few knowledge in network. 
I got a task in my internship.It is to mock a TCPClient by implement Interface.
The idea is that since we don't need to connect to the real server, we just need a mock TCPClient to receive data, save it and send it out. From what I understand, is it just to mock the sendmessage function in TCPClient??

```
public interface ITCPClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler when TCP client is connected 
    /// </summary>
    event ConnectionEventHandler Connected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for TCP Client on receiving data
    /// </summary>
    event DataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler when TCP client is disconnect
    /// </summary>
    event ConnectionEventHandler Disconnected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reports error when an error occurs
    /// </summary>
    event ErrorEventHandler OnError;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set whether to use HostByteOrder or NetworkByteorder with the socket - gateway expects network byte order
    /// </summary>
    bool ByteOrder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the client is running and connected to the server
    /// </summary>
    bool IsRunning { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the message to the sendqueue. The message will be processed by the ProcessMessage function waiting for the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message"></param>
    void SendMessage(string Message);

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the message to the sendqueue. The message willbe processed by the ProcessMessage function waiting for the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message"></param>
    void SendMessageHiPriority(string Message);

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the client and spawn the thread for processing the message
    /// </summary>
    void Start();

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects and stops listening for messages 
    /// </summary>
    void StopProcessing();

}

public class MockTCPClient : ITCPClient
{
    #region Private Fields

    private string msg;

    #endregion Private Fields


    #region Constructor

    public MockTCPClient()
    {
        //nothing 
    }


    #endregion Constructor

    #region event

    public event ConnectionEventHandler Connected;
    public event ConnectionEventHandler Disconnected;
    public event ErrorEventHandler OnError;
    public event DataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;

    #endregion event 

    #region property
    //question 
    public string ReceivedMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return msg;
        }

        set
        {
            msg = value;
        }

    }

    #endregion property

    //question??
    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, string e)
    {
        DataReceivedEventHandler dataReceived = DataReceived;
        if (dataReceived != null)
            dataReceived(this, e);
    }


    #region ITCPClient Members
    #region properties

    public bool ByteOrder { get; set; }


    public bool IsRunning { get; }

    #endregion properties

    public void SendMessage(string Message)
    {
        msg = Message;
    }

    public void SendMessageHiPriority(string Message)
    {    
    }

    public void Start()
    {
    }


    public void StopProcessing()
    {
    }


    #endregion ITCPClient Members

}
```

Comment: You can use a mocking framework instead of having to implement the entire interface. You configure only the parts that your need for your test and you are done. read up on Moq, NSubstitute and there are a few more. I would also suggest reading up on how a TcpClient works so that you have an idea of what you need to mock.

Comment: Can you clarify - what methods and properties of ITCPClient does your class need to interact with?

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes. The method is void SendMessage(string Message); And also I think event DataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived will also be considered. But I have no idea how to implement an event in C#. the method SendMessage is used to enqueue message in a queue which will be processed in the original TCPClient. I am not sure if I explain my question clearly. Thank you!

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you Nkosi. Yes. I just did some research on moq today and think it is a good idea but not sure if I am allowed to use the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demonstrates how Moq can verify that your class calls one of its methods.

This test
 - creates a mock of ITCPClient
 - specifies that the `SendMessage` method is verifiable - in other words, its usage will be tracked.
 - verifies that `SendMessage("test");` has been called on the mocked object.

The test will fail because it never calls `SendMessage("test");`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTcpClient()
{
    var mockedTcpClient = new Mock<ITCPClient>();
    mockedTcpClient.Setup(x => x.SendMessage(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    //mockedTcpClient.Object.SendMessage("test");
    mockedTcpClient.Verify(x=>x.SendMessage("test"));
}
```

If we uncomment the line that calls `SendMessage("test")` then the test will pass.

So in "real" usage you would create the `Mock` and use it in place of an `ITCPClient` when testing the class that depends on it. When it's done you can `Verify` that your class called `SendMessage` and passed the expected value.

If you can't use Moq, here's a totally different approach:

Create a class that implements `ITCPClient` as follows. You can leave most of the methods empty and just implement `SendMessage` along with a few other details:

```
public class TcpClientMock : ITCPClient
{
    private readonly List<string> _sentMessages;

    public TcpClientMock(List<string> sentMessages)
    {
        _sentMessages = sentMessages;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string Message)
    {
        _sentMessages.Add(Message);
    }

    //rest of non-implemented methods
}
```

In your unit test, do this:

```
var sentMessages = new List<string>();
var mockedTcpClient = new TcpClientMock(sentMessages);
```

Then create whatever class you're going to test and act on it. When it's done, see if `sentMessages` contains the message you expect.

---

As for receiving data, I suppose you'd need to tell your mocked object to raise that event so you could verify that your class responds as expected when the event is raised.  You could add a method to `TcpClientMock` like this:

```
public void SimulateDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventHandlerArgs args)
{
    DataReceived(sender, args);
}
```

That way when you've set up your class that depends on `ITCPClient` you can call `SimulateDataReceived` on the mock, causing it to raise the event, which in turn will cause your test subject to respond.

Comment: It looks very clear and I think I got the basic idea! Thank you so much for your response! And one more question. For unit test, do I also need to test SimulateDataReceived method?

Comment: If you have another question then start another question instead of using the comments. If this is correct then you should mark it as the answer. This helps other users who may have similar problems and also awards the user who answered some reputation. Your question was well written, so it got an upvote :)

Comment: You don't need to test `SimulateDataReceived` because that class itself is just a mock. That method is what you could use to simulate raising a `DataReceived` event. But if that's not something you need to simulate then you can totally disregard that.

Comment: @mark_h I am kinda new to stackoverflow. But thank you for the tips!

Comment: @ScottHannen Thank you Scott! In this case, it needs to be simulated. :)

Comment: Hi Linda.Cai - sorry if it sounded like I was complaining. We are all new at something. I was trying to explain how the site works (not that I am an expert).